# Issue when convert from <property> to p namspace in spring

Tags: java, spring

I had an existing spring application say App1 (not used spring annotation). Currently I am integrating some beans of this into another application say App2 which uses spring annotations for configuration.So I forced to use 'p' namespace for newly added beans. But after that the integrated application wont work.
This was my bean declaration in App1:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
  <bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />

<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="org.jbpm.runtime"></property>
```

This is the same in App2 which caused issue:

```
<bean id="vendor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:jpaVendorAdapter="vendor"
p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" 
p:persistenceUnitName="org.jbpm.runtime">
```

Is there anything wrong with this declaration?(both applications are spring 3.2)
Or is it must to use p namespace in annotation driven configurations.?

Comment: What do you mean by your application doesnt work? Is it giving error while deploying application OR at runtime it is throwing error due to properties not initialized? Please provide comprehensive details about your question.

Comment: While start up no exception regarding to 'entityManagerFactory' bean but throws can't instantiate bean 'messageUtil' due to on of its method could not be wired(as it uses annotation for autowire).But if we remove 'entityManagerFactory' bean from xml, application will work normally.I could not find its dependency

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this declaration if you didnt forget to declare `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` in beans element

Comment: Yes, It is declared in the xml file. Is there any issue with mixing annotation configuration with non annotated beans

Comment: There is no issue, we can mix injection thru annotations and p-properties. I suggest to make a simple test to see if it's true.

Comment: then <property> tag must be avoided?

Comment: You can also mix <property> and p-namespace, try it